# Slow performance wordpress sites

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, plesk, windows-server-2019

I recently migrated all my 4 websites from a Linux server to a Windows Server 2019 server. When the websites were on the Linux server I never had performance problems, while since I migrated the websites to Windows, 3 of the 4 websites take about 10 seconds to load a page.

I understood that the problem depends on the Url rewrite rules, because if I disable them the sites seem to go very fast, but some pages return a 404 error.

The only site that works well is a site that doesn't have worpress and doesn't need url rewrite rules. I manage all website with Plesk.

The rewrite rule in web.config file of the 3 websites is as follows:

```
<rule name="WordPress: https://www.truecv.net" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
    <match url="*"/>
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
        </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
</rule>
```

How can i fix it?

thanks in advance